# Are the following sentences correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

> 1. The first time I saw her was in a pub.
> 2. I first saw her in a pub.
> 3. I first saw her when I was in a pub.
> 4. The first time I saw her was when I was in a pub.
> 5. The first time I saw her in a pub was last week.

Which sentence is incorrect? Which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

1. You saw her for the first time, you were both in a pub.
2. Maybe you were in the pub as well, maybe you weren’t.
3. Maybe she was in the pub as well, maybe she wasn’t.
4. The same as 3.
5. You might have first seen her years ago, but until last week, you’d never seen her in a pub.

Comment: Are my 5 sentences grammatically correct?

Comment: They are all perfectly grammatical and read well. :)